# Enable scrolling in a react server side rendered app

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Hello I am migrating a react app from client side rendering(CSR) to server side rendering(SSR). I had implemented the code below in csr to enable loading more content when i scroll to the end of the page. The problem i am getting is its now giving an error that “ReferenceError: window is not defined” after migrating the code to ssr. How can i go about refactoring the code so that the scroll position works in react server side rendered app?

Code implemented in csr that enables scrolling

```
export class AllCourses extends React.PureComponent {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {

    };
    this.handleScroll();
  }

 .....

  handleScroll() {
    window.onscroll = () => {

      const nextPage = this.props.nextPage;
      if (
        window.innerHeight + document.documentElement.scrollTop ===
        document.documentElement.offsetHeight
      ) {
        this.props.dispatch(retrieveAllCourses(nextPage));
      }
    };
  }
```

Comment: This content loading is called lazy-loading. Anyway you can check this answer: https://sitecore.stackexchange.com/questions/16437/ssr-issue-window-not-defined

Comment: @freetyy Did you see my answer?

Comment: @VictorF,thanks for your answer. But when i scroll to the bottom of the page the first time, nothing happens. Then when i scroll back to the top of the page and scroll down again it works. I wonder why the scroll is working like that.

Comment: @freetyy I have made a [sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/great-river-4cnfr) that works - it's not SSR, though

Comment: I replaced the scroll logic to `if (document.documentElement.scrollTop + document.documentElement.clientHeight == document.documentElement.scrollHeight) {
          this.props.dispatch(retrieveAllCourses(nextPage));          
        }` and then it worked

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could move the logic in the `handleScroll` function into a useEffect callback, because when the component renders, the `window` variable is available.

So you would do like this:

```
componentDidMount() {
  if (typeof window !== 'undefined') {
    window.onscroll = () => {

      const nextPage = this.props.nextPage;
      if (
        window.innerHeight + document.documentElement.scrollTop ===
        document.documentElement.offsetHeight
      ) {
        this.props.dispatch(retrieveAllCourses(nextPage));
      }
    };
  }
}
```

Comment: or using lifecycle move into componentDidMount

Comment: Oh, didn't notice he used class components. Thanks